# Preventing amCharts tooltips from stretching with viewport when showTooltipOn = "always"

Tags: javascript, amcharts, amcharts4

Attempting to prevent tooltips from stretching out of their initial placement, unable to find a built in option. As pictured below all tooltips are stretching and remaining in the viewport at all time cluttering the display.

[Here's the tutorial on "sticky" tooltips](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/tutorials/using-sticky-tooltips/)

[Here's all available tooltip settings](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/reference/tooltip/)

[image: amChart Tooltip Issue]

```js
/**
 * ---------------------------------------
 * This demo was created using amCharts 4.
 * 
 * For more information visit:
 * https://www.amcharts.com/
 * 
 * Documentation is available at:
 * https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/
 * ---------------------------------------
 */

// Themes begin
am4core.useTheme(am4themes_animated);
// Themes end

/**
 * Define SVG path for target icon
 */
var targetSVG = "M9,0C4.029,0,0,4.029,0,9s4.029,9,9,9s9-4.029,9-9S13.971,0,9,0z M9,15.93 c-3.83,0-6.93-3.1-6.93-6.93S5.17,2.07,9,2.07s6.93,3.1,6.93,6.93S12.83,15.93,9,15.93 M12.5,9c0,1.933-1.567,3.5-3.5,3.5S5.5,10.933,5.5,9S7.067,5.5,9,5.5 S12.5,7.067,12.5,9z";

// Create map instance
var chart = am4core.create("chartdiv", am4maps.MapChart);

// Set map definition
chart.geodata = am4geodata_worldLow;

// Set projection
chart.projection = new am4maps.projections.Miller();

// Create map polygon series
var polygonSeries = chart.series.push(new am4maps.MapPolygonSeries());

// Exclude Antartica
polygonSeries.exclude = ["AQ"];

// Make map load polygon (like country names) data from GeoJSON
polygonSeries.useGeodata = true;

// Configure series
var polygonTemplate = polygonSeries.mapPolygons.template;
polygonTemplate.fill = chart.colors.getIndex(0).brighten(0.5).saturate(0.2);
polygonTemplate.strokeOpacity = 0.5;
polygonTemplate.strokeWidth = 0.5;

// create capital markers
var imageSeries = chart.series.push(new am4maps.MapImageSeries());

// Start map focuses on USA
chart.homeZoomLevel = 6;
chart.homeGeoPoint = {
  latitude: 30.8921,
  longitude: -77.0241
};

// define template
var imageSeriesTemplate = imageSeries.mapImages.template;
var circle = imageSeriesTemplate.createChild(am4core.Sprite);
circle.scale = 0.6;
circle.fill = chart.colors.getIndex(3).saturate(0.1).lighten(-0.5)
circle.path = targetSVG;
// what about scale...

// set propertyfields
imageSeriesTemplate.propertyFields.latitude = "latitude";
imageSeriesTemplate.propertyFields.longitude = "longitude";
imageSeriesTemplate.propertyFields.url = "url";

// open link, if any, in a new window
imageSeriesTemplate.urlTarget = "_blank";

imageSeriesTemplate.horizontalCenter = "middle";
imageSeriesTemplate.verticalCenter = "middle";
imageSeriesTemplate.align = "center";
imageSeriesTemplate.valign = "middle";
imageSeriesTemplate.width = 8;
imageSeriesTemplate.height = 8;
imageSeriesTemplate.nonScaling = true;
imageSeriesTemplate.tooltipText = "{title}";
imageSeriesTemplate.fill = am4core.color("#000");
imageSeriesTemplate.background.fillOpacity = 0;
imageSeriesTemplate.background.fill = "#fff";
imageSeriesTemplate.setStateOnChildren = true;
imageSeriesTemplate.showTooltipOn = "always";
//imageSeriesTemplate.states.create("hover");

imageSeries.data = [{
    "title": "Vienna",
    "latitude": 48.2092,
    "longitude": 16.3728
}, {
    "title": "Washington D.C.",
    "latitude": 38.8921,
    "longitude": -77.0241
}, {
    "title": "Minsk",
    "latitude": 53.9678,
    "longitude": 27.5766
}, {
    "title": "Brussels",
    "latitude": 50.8371,
    "longitude": 4.3676
}, {
    "title": "Sarajevo",
    "latitude": 43.8608,
    "longitude": 18.4214
}, {
    "title": "Sofia",
    "latitude": 42.7105,
    "longitude": 23.3238
}, {
    "title": "Abuja",
    "latitude": 9.058,
    "longitude": 7.4891
}, {
    "title": "Kigali",
    "latitude": -1.9441,
    "longitude": 30.0619
}, {
    "title": "Dakar",
    "latitude": 14.6953,
    "longitude": -17.4439
}, {
    "title": "Freetown",
    "latitude": 8.4697,
    "longitude": -13.2659
}, {
    "title": "Mogadishu",
    "latitude": 2.0411,
    "longitude": 45.3426
}, {
    "title": "Pretoria",
    "latitude": -25.7463,
    "longitude": 28.1876
}, {
    "title": "Mbabane",
    "latitude": -26.3186,
    "longitude": 31.141
}, {
    "title": "Dodoma",
    "latitude": -6.167,
    "longitude": 35.7497
}, {
    "title": "Lome",
    "latitude": 6.1228,
    "longitude": 1.2255
}, {
    "title": "Tunis",
    "latitude": 36.8117,
    "longitude": 10.1761
}];
```

```css
body {
  font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe UI", Roboto, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif, "Apple Color Emoji", "Segoe UI Emoji", "Segoe UI Symbol";
}

#chartdiv {
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/4/core.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/4/maps.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/4/geodata/worldLow.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/4/themes/animated.js"></script>
<div id="chartdiv"></div>
```